# One sample t-test equivalent for repeated measures design

Tags: t-test, repeated-measures, multiple-comparisons

I might be looking for something fairly obvious but here is my setup:

I have one group of participants who will perform multiple (different) tasks in an experiment. For each one of the tasks, I want to compare the performance of the participants against a given, fixed value. I might be comparing the tasks against each other as well (then using a linear mixed model) but this does not help me for the comparison to the constant.

When looking at the design, I am tempted to perform multiple one-sample t-tests and correcting for alpha error inflation.
However, I have a feeling that I might be missing a better fitting approach.

Therefore I would like to find an answer to the following question:
Is there a validated approach to compare data from repeated measure designs against a (non-changing) constant value?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of options:

You can still do this using a mixed effects model, it sounds like you would be fitting only the intercept as fixed (then include your random effects to account for the grouping).  The intercept is then the estimate of the overall mean.

To use this information to test the mean against a fixed value you can compute the confidence interval for the intercept/grand mean then see if the fixed null value is in the confidence interval.

Another approach is to subtract the fixed null value from all of the $y$ values (response values) then fit the mixed effects model on the adjusted response.  The test that the intercept in this model is different from 0 is the test that the intercept on the original scale is different from your null value.

If using R, you can include the fixed null value in an `offset` so that the tests and CI now give what you want.  There is probably similar functionality in other tools, I am just not familiar enough with them to point you the correct direction.

You could  fit a hierarchical Bayesian model (similar to the mixed effects model)  then not worry about formal testing but compare your fixed values of interest to the posterior distribution.

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, just for clarification: I understood your first two approaches in a way that they test the grand mean over all trials against the constant. However, for my design I would actually be interested in the performance in the separate trials/tasks (averaged over participants) against the constant. Did I misunderstand your approaches or did I phrase my question poorly?

Comment: @Dom42, did each subject to a given task multiple times?  if yes, then I would analyze each task by itself with the mixed effects model.  If each subject did each task only once, then you can analyze each task without worrying about random effects.  If you want to analyze all tasks at once (assume the error variance is the same) then you can do above, just compare the fixed null value for each task to the mean for that group, or subtract the fixed null from the response corresponding to that value.

Comment: Thanks once again. Each participant will only do a task once, therefore I'm actually not that worried about the random effects but rather about the alpha error inflation (as I would perform as many one-sample t-tests as tasks exist). I was just wondering, if there isn't a better approach for this design case.

Comment: @Dom42, if each subject only does each task once and your main concern is inflating type I error, then search for "Adjust for multiple comparisons" or "False Discovery Rate".

Comment: thanks for the advice! As mentioned in my inital post, I was aware, that this would be a possibility (that's what I meant with the remark on correcting for alpha error inflation). However, I was under the impression that a more appropriate method should/could be available, but apparently, this is not the case. Thank you!